# Cannot send the array in response after using a async firestore database call

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Send an array in response in firebase functions using Nodejs. I am not able to send the array.

I have tried to send a response in the loop. It works but only sends one value.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let db = admin.firestore();
var dat =[];
var dat1 =[];

db.collection('users').get().then(function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(element => {
  //  snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
  db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('profile').doc(doc.id).collection("pet").doc(doc.id).get().then((snapshot) => { 

      //  dat.push(snapshot.data()['bio']+"");
    dat.push(element.id);
  });
  return snapshot;
})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
   });


  dat.forEach(element =>{
    db.collection('users').doc(element.id).collection('profile').doc(element.id).collection('pet').doc(element.id).get().then((snapshot) =>{
      dat1.push(snapshot.data()['bio']);
      return snapshot;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
     });
  });

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(function(request, response){
    response.send(dat1);
});
```

It always appears empty but it should have an array in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply declare some top-level code and expect them to run (and complete) before your function is invoked.

All code that must execute when the function gets invoked should be inside the `exports.helloWorld` function, or be invoked from there.

So something like:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(function(request, response){
  var dat =[];
  var dat1 =[];

  db.collection('users').get().then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(element => {
    //  snapshot.forEach(function(doc){

 db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('profile').doc(doc.id).collection("pet").doc(doc.id).get().then((snapshot) => { 

        //  dat.push(snapshot.data()['bio']+"");
      dat.push(element.id);
    });
    return snapshot;
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
     });


    dat.forEach(element =>{
      db.collection('users').doc(element.id).collection('profile').doc(element.id).collection('pet').doc(element.id).get().then((snapshot) =>{
        dat1.push(snapshot.data()['bio']);
        return snapshot;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
       });
    });
    response.send(dat1);
});
```

I'm not sure I understand the structure of the code you had outside of the `helloWorld` function, so I just copy/pasted it in the right spot above to show you what needs to happen.